# Should JPA Entity Manager be closed in EJB?

Tags: jpa, ejb, weblogic

I have the following message driven bean in which first of all I perform necessary db lookups (1), then I call an external system (2) (response time can vary from a couple of seconds up to 2 minutes), and after that I update some db tables (3). Since I do not understand which resources are hold by the entity manager my question is if it does make sense to:

- close the entity manager after db lookups (1) are completed
- create a new entity manager using the EntityManagerFactory after external
  system response is received

Furthermore I'd like to know if there is an advantage in using EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() instead of EntityManager injection.

Thanks in advance

Container: WebLogic Server 10.3.3

MDB code:

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"
        ) })
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyBean implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "pu1")
    private EntityManagerFactory    emf;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyBean.class);

    public MyBean() {}

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message incomingMsg) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try{
            if(incomingMsg instanceof TextMessage){
                em = this.emf.createEntityManager()
                //perform db lookups (1)
                ...
                em.close()
                //call external system (response time up to 2 min) (2)
                ...
                //db update (3)
                em = this.emf.createEntityManager()
                ...
            } else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported message type");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("Message processing failed. Forcing the associated transaction to rollback", ex);
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        } finally{
            if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to leave the EntityManager open (actually the specification says that even if you close the EntityManager the persistence context will remain open until the transaction commits or rolls back). You should worry instead about your transaction, as it may time out if the response of the external system call is too slow. Do you really want that call to be part of the transaction? Is it a XA transaction? Otherwise you may want to re-factor your code so that the call to the external system is not part of a transaction.

Comment: Could you please explain at which moment a transaction is created? I just perform DB lookups before the ext system call, no inserts or updates.

Comment: You annotated the onMessage method with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED, so when you enter the method a transaction will be started or the exiting transaction will be joined.

Comment: Yes, it is an XA transaction. I want to achieve the following behaviour: 
-read message from the input queue in a transaction
-if something goes wrong (e.g. the call to the ext sys times out or another exception occurs) the transaction is rolled back (JMS message remains in the input queue, db updates if any are rolled back)
I don't think its possible to make the call to the ext sys outside the transaction. Do you?

Could you please explain what happens then you close the entity manager? Are some resources like DB connections released? (sorry, I'm not familier with JPA yet)